# VB6 null boolean

Tags: vb6, boolean

I'm working on an application in vb6 that draws information from a database. I've come across many problems that come from null values in the database as vb6 functions and subroutines don't like nulls. The string problem is easily solved by concatenating an empty string to the value. But what do I do for a null value where a boolean should be?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Null means "there is no value" so I have no clue how you'd expect the compiler to guess what you intended.  Just code to test for Null and take action as appropriate.  This is what Null is for, it isn't a bug or deficiency.

Your question is like asking what to do with an Integer that is equal to 3 when in your head you've modeled things so only 1 and 2 are valid.  If you don't want Null to have meaning don't store Null in the database.

Comment: I didn't write the database. I just have to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes you are using the ADO objects for data access.

```
Dim boolField As Boolean
If Not IsNull(fields("FieldName").value) Then
    boolField = CBool(fields("FieldName").value)
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using most of these function to handle nulls

```
'--- type-casting without errors'
Public Function C2Str(Value As Variant) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    C2Str = CStr(Value)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Function C2Lng(Value As Variant) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    C2Lng = CLng(Value)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Function C2Cur(Value As Variant) As Currency
    On Error Resume Next
    C2Cur = CCur(Value)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Function C2Dbl(Value As Variant) As Double
    On Error Resume Next
    C2Dbl = CDbl(Value)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Function C2Date(Value As Variant) As Date
    On Error Resume Next
    C2Date = CDate(Value)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Function C2Bool(Value As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    C2Bool = CBool(Value)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

You can use `C2Bool` in your case :-))

Answer (score 0):

Try using `isnull` and specifying the .value of the field, as otherwise the isnull() checks the field object (and not the value):

```
If (IsNull(l_BankAccount.Recordset.Fields("BANKCODE").value) = True) Or _
```

Comment: Linking to a paying forum like Expert-Exchange seems a very odd idea to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old problem with VB6 and ASP. I use `Trim(l_BankAccount.Recordset.Fields("BANKCODE").value & " ")` which gets rid of many problems including the dbNull.
For a whole number field `CLng("0" & Trim(l_BankAccount.Recordset.Fields("BANKCODE").value & " "))`
works.